# How to read Text "after-formatting" in Excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cells that contain floating point values that are then formatted as Percentages by the formatting of the cells they're stored in. I then need to read this value and concatenate it into a string. But when I do this, the value that gets Concatenated is using the raw floating point number, and not the formatted Percentage I want.

To give an example:

[image: Incorrect Formatting]

The values in the `%` column are indeed the `-0.101443582441324` values seen in `Column1`, but I've used the Cell Format options to change it to a percentage value.

The correct text in `Column1` should be something like this:

```
\text{-10.144%}
\text{-10.696%}
\text{-11.290%}
```

But instead it's picking up the underlying values of the cells, pre-formatting.

The formula used in `Column1` is `=CONCATENATE("\text{",D2,"}")`

How can I change the formula in the `Column1` columns to produce the correct text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `TEXT()` function - should be something like the following:

```
="\text{"&TEXT(D2,"00.000%")&"}"
```

[image: img1]